# pointer as second argument instead of returning pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

I noticed that it is a common idiom in C to accept an un-`malloc`ed pointer as a second argument instead of returning a pointer. Example:

```
/*function prototype*/    
void create_node(node_t* new_node, void* _val, int _type);

/* implementation */
node_t* n;
create_node(n, &someint, INT)
```

Instead of

```
/* function prototype */
node_t* create_node(void* _val, int _type)

/* implementation */
node_t* n = create_node(&someint, INT)
```

What are the advantages and/or disadvantages of both approaches?

Thanks!

**EDIT** Thank you all for your answers. The motivations for choice 1 are very clear to me now (and I should point out that the pointer argument for choice 1 **should be** malloc'd contrary to what I originally thought).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Accepting* a pointer (which the caller is responsible for malloc'ing or not) to memory to be filled in, offers serious advantages in flexibility over *returning* a pointer (necessarily malloc'ed).  In particular, if the caller knows it needs to use whatever's returned only within a certain function, it can pass in the address of a stack-allocated struct or array; if it knows it doesn't need reentrancy, it can pass in the address of a `static` struct or array -- in either case, a malloc/free pair gets saved, and such savings do mount up!-)

Comment: This. The ability to do `struct thing t; init_thing(&t);` is nice.

Comment: If I wanted to write a function to copy a linked list, would I have a function prototype like `void copy_list(node_t* new_head, node_t* original_head)`? I think I would have to malloc a new node for each in the original list and add it to the 'end' of new_head (copy the val and type but give it a new `node_t* next` pointer value). Is this the best way of going about it?

Comment: @Tyler, consider `copy_list(node_t **new_head, const node_t* original_head)` as a possibly preferable signature for that function (although is this peculiar case _returning_ a `node_t *` is surely also a reasonable possibility).

Comment: @Alex

Which one would you use/which one do you usually see?

Comment: @Tyler, in others' code I see a lot of "returning a pointer" (for such tasks as copying lists) -- when I contribute to an existing library or program I follow the same style as other existing code, when I code from scratch I usually prefer passing pointer-to-pointer, using `const` accurately, and using the return value as a "success or error" code (like e.g. many Unix system calls do).

Comment: @Alex

Thanks for the quick reply! I really appreciate the clarity with which you answered my question. :)

Answer (score 6):

That doesn't make much sense. Pointers in C are passed by value, just like other objects—the difference lies in the value. With pointers, the value is the memory address, which is passed to the function. However, you're still duplicating the value, and so when you `malloc`, you'll be changing the value of the pointer inside your function, not the one on the outside.

```
void create_node(node_t* new_node, void* _val, int _type) {
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(node_t) * SIZE);
    // `new_node` points to the new location, but `n` doesn't.
    ...
}

int main() {
    ...
    node_t* n = NULL;
    create_node(n, &someint, INT);
    // `n` is still NULL
    ...
}
```

There are three ways to avoid this. The first is, as you mentioned, returning the new pointer from the function. The second is to take a pointer to the pointer, thereby passing it by reference:

```
void create_node(node_t** new_node, void* _val, int _type) {
    *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node_t) * SIZE);
    // `*new_node` points to the new location, as does `n`.
    ...
}

int main() {
    ...
    node_t* n = NULL;
    create_node(&n, &someint, INT);
    // `n` points to the new location
    ...
}
```

The third is to simply `malloc` `n` outside the function call:

```
int main() {
    ...
    node_t* n = malloc(sizeof(node_t) * SIZE);
    create_node(n, &someint, INT);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting that major error in my understanding. :)

Comment: I should probably add that I agree with Alex Martelli: the third method is definitely the best for the majority of cases.

Answer (score 2):

I usually prefer receiving pointers (property initialized) as function arguments as opposed to returning a pointer to a memory area that has been malloc'ed inside the function. With this approach you are making explicit that the responsibility of memory management is on the user's side.

Returning pointers usually leads to memory leaks, as it's easier to forget to free() your pointers if you didn't malloc()'ed them.

Comment: "It's easier to forget to free() your pointers if you didn't malloc()'ed them." Not sure I agree with that, but I worked for 7 years on a system which didn't free memory on process exit. That teaches you how to write leak-free code.

Comment: I don't mean like... "always", but maybe a novice does not imagine that the pointer that the function returns has been malloced inside it. It's more a taste-thing :]

Comment: @Steve

What was the system and what's the advantage of that?

Comment: @Tyler: embedded/hosted/weirdly portable RTOS called "intent". Various advantages/necessities. Memory overhead: there only needed to be one global memory allocator for the system, no per-process heaps. It didn't have virtual memory or kernel space/mode, so everything was in process context. Signals were only supported grudgingly, and disabled much of the time, so you could assume/arrange you wouldn't be killed and leak because of that. `malloc` and `free` did track memory on a per-process basis and free at exit, and were signal-safe, but most systems programming used lower-level allocation.

Comment: @mgv: yes, I think I know what you mean, it's just that my training was basically "never, ever call a function without knowing (a) resource ownership, (b) all its error modes, (c) can it be called with signals disabled, (d) can it be called with signals *enabled*, (e) can it be called in interrupt context, and if not can I, (f) is there any other way I can screw this up? (g) etc".

Answer (score 1):

I usually don't make a fixed choice, I cleanly put it into its own library and provide the best of both worlds.

```
void node_init (node_t *n);

void node_term (node_t *n);

node_t *node_create ()
{
    node_t *n = malloc(sizeof *n);
    /* boilerplate error handling for malloc returning NULL goes here */
    node_init(n);
    return n;
}

void node_destroy (node_t *n)
{
    node_term(n);
    free(n);
}
```

For every malloc there should be a free, thus for every init there should be a term and for every create there should be a destroy. As your objects grow more complex, you will find that you begin to nest them. Some higher level object may use a node_t list for internal data management. Before freeing this object, the list must be freed first. _init and _term care for this, completely hiding this implementation detail.

There can be decisions about further details, e.g. destroy may take a node_t **n and set *n to NULL after freeing it.

Answer (score 0):

personally I like to return data using refernce or pointer params, and use the function return for returning error codes.

Answer (score 0):

1) As Samir pointed out the code is incorrect, pointer is passed by value, you need **

2) The function is essentially a constructor, so it makes sense for it to both allocate the memory and init the data structure.  Clean C code is almost always object oriented like that with constructors and destructors.

3) Your function is void, but it should be returning int so that it can return errors.  There will be at least 2, probably 3 possible error conditions: malloc can fail, type argument can be invalid and possibly value can be out of range.

Answer (score 0):

An issue not discussed in this article is the matter of how you go about referring to the malloc'ed buffer within the function that allocates it, and presumably, stores something in it before it returns control to its caller.

In the case that brought me to this page, I have a function that passes in a pointer, which receives the address of an array of HOTKEY_STATE structures. The prototype declares the argument as follows.

```
HOTKEY_STATE ** plplpHotKeyStates
```

The return value, ruintNKeys, is the number of elements in the array, which is determined by the routine before the buffer is allocated. Rather than use malloc() directly, however, I used calloc, as follows.

```
*plplpHotKeyStates = ( HOTKEY_STATE * ) calloc ( ruintNKeys ,
                                                 sizeof ( HOTKEY_STATE ) ) ;
```

After I verify that plplpHotKeyStates is no longer null, I defined a local pointer variable, hkHotKeyStates, as follows.

```
HOTKEY_STATE * hkHotKeyStates = *plplpHotKeyStates ;
```

Using this variable, with an unsigned integer for a subscript, the code populates the structures, using the simple member operator (.), as shown below.

```
hkHotKeyStates [ uintCurrKey ].ScanCode = SCANCODE_KEY_ALT ;
```

When the array is fully populated, it returns ruintNKeys, and the caller has everything it needs to process the array, either in the conventional way, using the reference operator (->), or by employing the same technique that I used in the function to gain direct access to the array.