# Why do many init functions take a pointer to initialize, rather than returning a valid one?

Tags: c, pointers, init

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pointer as second argument instead of returning pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520777/pointer-as-second-argument-instead-of-returning-pointer)

I see this a lot:

```
Monkey* test = malloc(sizeof(Monkey));
Monkey_New(test);
```

Wouldn't it be cleaner to have the init function return the pointer?

```
Monkey* test = Monkey_New();
```

Why is it frequently done in the first way?

Comment: If your first code alternative includes a memory allocation such as `test = malloc(sizeof *test);` between the definition of `test` and the call to `Monkey_New`, then you should show it. Otherwise, this code is nonsensical because it passes an uninitialized object to Monkey_New.

Comment: Your first example is wrong. It should be Monkey_New(&test). Otherwise it is impossible to allocate the pointer in the 'Monkey_New' function which only receives a copy of the pointer given as parameter.

Comment: Yep, never did fix that... whoops

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two designs are functionally extremely different. The one you're asking about puts the burden of allocation on the caller. This has a huge advantage that dynamic storage (`malloc`) can be avoided if the object does not have to out-live the caller; it can be stored in an automatic variable. This also means that, assuming the init function does not have to obtain further resources, you can have a failure-free API where the caller does not have to check for failure. On the other hand, it requires that the definition (at least the size) of the structure be exposed to the calling module, which means the caller must be recompiled if the library code is updated to use an object of a larger size; thus it can be negative for shared libraries intended to have a long-term stable ABI.

In the alternative design you pointed out, the burden of obtaining storage is on the callee (library function), and it must use dynamic storage (`malloc`) since automatic storage would not survive the return to the caller. This is more abstract and cleaner,

Comment: Thanks; I hadn't considered that. My thinking was clouded, I think, by working with lots of heap-only structures lately.

Comment: The size need not be exposed at build time. The size can be provided by a run-time routine. Then changing the size in different versions of the software does not require recompiling users of the library.

Comment: @Eric: Then the caller still has to use dynamic storage unless you want to get into ugly VLA hacks (ugly because it's non-trivial to ensure the alignment in any portable way).

Comment: @R.. Good answer, but I would not classify the alternative design as "cleaner" because who frees the object?  If the caller ever gives out the pointer that it obtained, then you have chaos.  The first option separates memory management from "object" function, which is cleaner IMHO.  Also, for systems that never use malloc, the first option is the only easy way.

Comment: Also, if it was written like this size_t Monkey_New(void*, size_t max_size), then you can somewhat cope with the library changing types.  You must hide the Monkey behind the interface, and also provide a size_t Monkey_sizeof(void).

Comment: @Josh: Whoever owns the object frees it. Standard "OO" design in C is that you have creation/allocation functions that create a new object of their type, and a corresponding free/destruction function that's called to end their lifetime. Everything is dynamic storage duration and treated as such. I find it painful to have to use dynamic storage duration even when you don't want it, so I like the first version better, but the standard version is a lot more idiomatic in "OO C" from my experience.

Comment: @R.. Who owns it? That is the question.  I think we are on the same side of the fence here and hopefully the OP is getting use out of this.  As an embedded programmer where malloc is sometimes considered a dangerous and unusable word, and as a C programmer that doesn't have the built-in functionality of constructors/destructors (so no RAII and smart pointers), I'd consider the first version the only real option (unless you just live your life on the desktop where memory is cheap and plentiful).

Comment: The caller owns it. It may pass ownership to some other part of the program (e.g. by storing the pointer in a data structure with storage duration that will outlive the caller, e.g. some sort of long-lived tree or hash table) or it might destroy/free it before returning. Again I'm in complete agreement with you about avoiding `malloc`, but sometimes you need dynamic storage for long-lived data, and I'm just explaining what the prevailing idiom in "OO C" code is, not claiming it's the right way to program.

Answer (score -1):

It's all depends on the naming convention used by the developers. Take into consideration this:

http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Default_Constructors

for c++ and c, tells you to use new and takes parameters to help initialization, returning the value initialized. In the past, it was not the case, because it was a wild world back then. For the sake of decency, use Monkey_New();